# RegEx to extract "SELECT [whatever] FROM INSERTED"

Tags: regex

I'm trying to pick `SELECT` statements out of a block of text (*e.g.*, a trigger).

All the SELECT statements will be of the form:

> <kbd>SELECT</kbd> <kbd>(.+)</kbd> <kbd>FROM INSERTED</kbd>

In other words, i need all the `SELECT` statements from the a table called `INSERTED`.

## Research Effort

I try the obvious regex:

```
SELECT (.+?) FROM INSERTED
```

This works for: (https://regex101.com/r/4FWbIx/1)

```
SELECT 'Hello, world!' FROM INSERTED i
```

But it doesn't handle: (https://regex101.com/r/4FWbIx/2)

```
   SELECT⏎
      TOP(10)⏎
      CustomerID,⏎
      Name,⏎
      Address⏎
   FROM INSERTED i
```

because there is no `SPACE` after `SELECT` and before `FROM`.

Simple fix, remove the spaces; while being sure that *single-line mode* *(**s**)* is enabled: (https://regex101.com/r/4FWbIx/3)

```
SELECT(.+)FROM INSERTED
```

And while that works for most cases:

[image]

But it falls over dead with there is the stray word `SELECT` anywhere in there:

[image]

Sandbox where you can test: https://regex101.com/r/4FWbIx/4

Comment: Do you mean with a tempered greedy token? `\bSELECT(?:(?!\bSELECT\b).)*FROM INSERTED\b` https://regex101.com/r/OohZpu/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search for all the characters that does not have 'SELECT' next to it until the cursor reaches 'FROM' as below

```regex
SELECT((?:(?!SELECT).)*)FROM INSERTED
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4FWbIx/6)

---

If you don't want to capture spaces along with column names, use below.

```regex
SELECT\s+((?:(?!SELECT).)*)\s+FROM INSERTED
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4FWbIx/7)

---

**Edit**: Changed the position of dot to make it tampered greedy token. Thanks Wiktor for pointing out this.